# Sleep with earplugs but still hear alarm

Tags: sleeping, work

Where I sleep I can easily be awaken by the sounds of my neighbors. Therefore I usually wear earplugs to sleep. Because I work flextime, this is not a problem. However there are certain deadlines which I have to meet. I usually don't hear the alarm while wearing earplugs. What are some methods to still hear the alarm while wearing earplugs to sleep?

Comment: Get smart bulbs, you can program them to light up at the time you wish to wake up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't rely on just your muted hearing for the wake-up call. Try a multimedia approach with a timer

An inexpensive electric timer can be set to turn on both a vibrator and a bright light at the same time. The combination will be more effective in addition to anything you're using now.

Put both the vibrator and the lamp where they will disturb you on cue. The timer is pretty dependable as they work with synchronous motors the same as electric clocks. The only thing missing will be the displayed time. For that actual indication, use a regular alarm clock plugged into a different electric socket from the timer. ;)

For a dollar or two more, you can get a small "button flasher" that blinks the light.
[image: button flasher]
The flasher button is put into the light bulb socket - screw the light bulb back into the socket to hold the button in place.

When the timer activates, the bulb will flash and the vibrator will pull you back into reality.

Good Morning!

Comment: Bought a cheap LED lamp and electric timer...Best method to get up early...

Answer (score 6):

If you have a smart watch or health watch, those can frequently be used as alarm clocks that vibrate. I find it very effective as something vibrating on your wrist in the middle of the night is quite disconcerting.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two (or maybe three) options.

1) Buy a clock with a louder alarm. Depending on how loud the alarm needs to be, you might even buy one of those old-fashioned alarm clocks with two bells on the top and a small metal mallet that rattles between them.

2) Buy an alarm clock that uses light instead of sound to wake you up. These are generally made for people with hearing impairments.

3) (This may or may not be an option, depending on your living situation.) If someone else lives with you, and they generally wake up before you, ask them to wake you up at a particular time.

Answer (score 2):

Set the alarm clock in or in front of a something bowl-shaped (like a bowl for example) to direct and amplify the sound.

Answer (score 0):

Get a pair of closed-back, in-the-ear headphones to use as earplugs. Plug them into your phone so the alarm sound plays in the headphones

Answer (score 0):

Smartphone alarm utilizing integrated flashlight, like SleepAsAndroid + (if necessary) a smartwatch. Even better: a constant sleep rythm and strong incentives ‒ at best a burning desire.

Answer (score -2):

Smart watches can set alarms and set them to vibrate. My bpdoctormed smartwatch works fine.

Comment: That answer has already been given.